# How to extract raw data from Salesforce using Beatbox python API

Tags: python, salesforce, beatbox

I am using the following code to extract data from Salesforce using beatbox python API.

```
import beatbox
sf_username = "xyz@salesforce.com"
sf_password = "123"
sf_api_token = "ABC"


def extract():
   sf_client = beatbox.PythonClient()
   password = str("%s%s" % (sf_password, sf_api_token))
   sf_client.login(sf_username, password)
   lead_qry = "SELECT CountryIsoCode__c,LastModifiedDate FROM Country limit 10"
   records = sf_client.query(lead_qry)
   output = open('output','w')
   for record in records:
     output.write('\t'.join(record.values())
   output.close()

if _name_ == '__main__':
 extract()
```

But this is what I get in the output. How to get the raw data, just the values I see in the workbench. I don't want to parse each datatype and get the raw value.

Actual Output:

> [{'LastModifiedDate': datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 2, 9, 32, 4),
>   'CountryIsoCode_*c': 'AU', 'type': 'Country*_c', 'Id': ''},
>   {'LastModifiedDate': datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 18, 14, 0, 21),
>   'CountryIsoCode_*c': 'LX', 'type': 'Country*_c', 'Id': ''},
>   {'LastModifiedDate': datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 12, 15, 20, 11),
>   'CountryIsoCode_*c': 'AE', 'type': 'Country*_c', 'Id': ''},
>   {'LastModifiedDate': datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 12, 15, 20, 29),
>   'CountryIsoCode_*c': 'AR', 'type': 'Country*_c', 'Id': ''},
>   {'LastModifiedDate': datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 2, 9, 32, 4),
>   'CountryIsoCode_*c': 'AT', 'type': 'Country*_c', 'Id': ''},
>   {'LastModifiedDate': datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 2, 9, 32, 4),
>   'CountryIsoCode_*c': 'BE', 'type': 'Country*_c', 'Id': ''},
>   {'LastModifiedDate': datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 12, 15, 21, 28),
>   'CountryIsoCode_*c': 'BR', 'type': 'Country*_c', 'Id': ''},
>   {'LastModifiedDate': datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 12, 15, 21, 42),
>   'CountryIsoCode_*c': 'CA', 'type': 'Country*_c', 'Id': ''},
>   {'LastModifiedDate': datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 12, 15, 36, 18),
>   'CountryIsoCode_*c': 'CH', 'type': 'Country*_c', 'Id': ''},
>   {'LastModifiedDate': datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 12, 15, 35, 8),
>   'CountryIsoCode_*c': 'CL', 'type': 'Country*_c', 'Id': ''}]

Expected Output:

```
AU 2012-11-02T09:32:04Z
LX 2012-08-18T14:00:21Z
```

Comment: When you're running the lead_qry, salesforce returns a sObject, not just the individual fields. Workbench, I believe, does the parsing for you. A sObject, however, parses easily into JSON, which can than be easily accessed to get the raw values that you're looking for. Why not do that?

Answer (score 4):

If you work with table data you should use Pandas library

Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import datetime
import beatbox

service = beatbox.PythonClient()  
service.login('login_here', 'creds_here')


query_result = service.query("SELECT Name, Country, CreatedDate FROM Lead limit 5")  # CreatedDate is a datetime object
records = query_result['records']      # records is a list of dictionaries
```

records is a list of dictionaries as you mentioned before

```
df = pd.DataFrame(records)
print (df)

     Country         CreatedDate Id              Name  type
0  United States 2011-05-26 23:39:58       qwe qwe      Lead
1         France 2011-09-01 08:45:26       qwe qwe      Lead
2         France 2011-09-01 08:37:36       qwe qwe      Lead
3         France 2011-09-01 08:46:38       qwe qwe      Lead
4         France 2011-09-01 08:46:57       qwe qwe      Lead
```

Now you have table-style Dataframe object. You can index multiple columns and rows:

```
df['CreatedDate']

0   2011-05-26 23:39:58
1   2011-09-01 08:45:26
2   2011-09-01 08:37:36
3   2011-09-01 08:46:38
4   2011-09-01 08:46:57
```

Here is more about pandas time functionality http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html

And here is about pandas http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html